# ChatBox weird appending of message

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, chat

Hello its me again I have a chatbox that is loaded via clicking a link. BTW I am using jquery ui chatbox initially the chat_div is hidden.

Initially it works as I wanted it to be, but if I click another user and click the chat link to chat with the user the only right thing it display is the title of the chatbox but the messages it append are the ones from the previous user.

Here's the click event for the chatbox:

```
    <?php global $despId; ?>
    <?php foreach($usersas $x) {?>

    <?php $despId = $x->user_id?>
    <a href="#" class="chatOpener" id="<?php echo $despId?>">Chat with user</a>
    <?php } ?>      
    <?php echo br(2)?>

<div id="chat_div"></div>

    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
    $('#chat_div').hide();
    $(".chatOpener").live('click', function(event, ui){
                          var despID = $(this).attr('id');
                          box = null;
                          $('#chat_div').show();
                          //alert('1');

                        setInterval (load_messages, 2500);
                          if(box){
                              box.chatbox("option", "boxManager").toggleBox();
                          }
                          else {
                              box = $("#chat_div").chatbox({id: username, 
                                                            user:{key : username},
                                                            title : "<?php echo $x->firstName.' '.$x->lastName?>",
                                                            messageSent : function(id, user, msg) {

                                                                $.post('<?php echo site_url('/chats/addMessage')?>', {
                                                                            'username': '0', 
                                                                            'sendto' : '<?php echo $despId?>', 
                                                                            'message' : msg});

                                                                //$("#log").append(id + " said: " + msg + "<br/>");
                                                                $("#chat_div").chatbox("option", "boxManager").addMsg(id, msg);
                                                            }});
                                                            return false;
                          }
                          return false;
                      });


                      function load_messages(){
                            $('#chat_div').load('<?php echo site_url('/chats/index/'.$despId);?>');
                      }
                });
<?php }?>
```

I wonder where is the weird behavior lies. I have been working this like days ago already and still no luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only thing wrong I saw was the foreach line, try changing this:

```
<?php foreach($usersas $x) {?>
```

To this:

```
<?php foreach($users as $x) {?>
```

Hope it helps (=